# Best way to decrypt ciphertext?

Tags: c++, encryption

Here is my code for encrypting plaintext, and then decrypting the ciphertext back to plaintext.  I'm having issues on what to put in the decrypt function, to allow for the keys to be used as i enter plaintext and encrypt as well as decrypt.  Sorry for editing the main question, but I'm not able to put the main code into a comment as its too long.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int pos = 0;                                //current pad position
int pad[65] =                               //our OTP array
    {8, 19, 13, 4,  23,
    22, 5,  23, 10, 16,
    5,  14, 3,  6,  21,
    20, 23, 9,  4,  18,
    6,  13, 17, 24, 16,
    2,  15, 15, 3,  24,
    15, 3,  2,  5,  19,
    6,  18, 15, 22, 19,
    18, 19, 3,  7,  11,
    18, 13, 8,  25, 16,
    9,  5,  18, 19, 9,
    20, 10, 19, 15, 2,
    5,  22, 20, 3,  23};
string encrypt(string plaintext)            //encryption function
{
    string ciphertext;
    for(int i=0; i<plaintext.size();i++)    //cycle through the plaintext
    {
        int num = plaintext[i] - 'A';       //convert to numbers
        num = (num + pad[pos++]) % 26;      //apply modular addition
        ciphertext.push_back(num + 'A');    //convert back to letters
    }

    return ciphertext;                      //return the ciphertext
}

string decrypt(string ciphertext)
{
    /*
    We will reset the pad position for decryption to start from the same point as the encryption for the first string. 
    For encrypting/decrypting multiple strings, make sure that we don't reuse the same pad characters for subsequent encryptions. 
    pos should not by reset to 0 everytime but to the length of the previously encoded string 
    */
    string plaintext;
  pos=0;
    //write your decryption routine here
    for(int i=0; i<ciphertext.size();i++)   //cycle through the plaintext
    {
        int num = ciphertext[i] - 'A';      //convert to numbers
        num = (num + pad[pos++]) % 26;      //apply modular addition
        plaintext.push_back(num + 'A'); //convert back to letters
    }
  return plaintext;
}

int main()
{
    string plaintext;               //encrypt plaintext HAPPY
    string ciphertext;
    int answers;
    ciphertext = encrypt(plaintext);
    while(true){
    cout<<"Select (1) Encrypt, (2) Decrypt:, (3) Quit"<< endl;
    cin>>answers;
    if(answers == 1){
    cout<< "Enter PT: ";
    cin>>plaintext;
    cout<< "Ciphertext = " << encrypt(plaintext)<<endl;
    }
  if(answers == 2){
    string plaintext;               //encrypt plaintext HAPPY
      string ciphertext;
    cout<<"Enter CT: ";
    cin>>ciphertext;
    cout<< "Plaintext = " << decrypt(ciphertext)<<endl;
      }
  if(answers == 3){
        return 0;
      }
    }
  if (answers != 1 || 2 || 3){
   return -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your post and **TAG** your question with the programming language you are using (Java, PHP,...) - this will increase the chance you will get an answer (most "specialists" just search for "their" language" and won't see your question). To answer your question [in pseudocode]: "print decrypt(encrypt("TEST"))" will receive "TEST".

Comment: I apologize, it is in C++.  when i run the code, my encrypt plaintext works as expected, but when i run the decrypt ciphertext, it doesn't give the right answer.  I'm stuck as to what needs to be changed in my decrypt function.

Comment: I find it unlikely that adding X to num is the inverse of adding X to num.  encrypt and decrypt look identical.  I think decrypt should probably have `- pad[pos++]`  (be careful with signed arithmetic and modulus)  Might be sufficient to write `num = (num + 26 - pad[pos++]) % 26;`

Comment: Add a main that demonstrates the problem. What is `pad`? `encrypt` doesn’t define `pos`. Make a [mcve].

Comment: Also, once you get it working, be careful with `pad`.  What is the length of `pad`?  Instead of `pos++` you should probably have `pos = (pos + 1) % length_of_pad`.

Answer (score 0):

You are encrypting letters by converting them to a number X, adding some K to that number and taking that modulo 26.

To encrypt:
`X' = (X + K) % 26`

Therefore, to decrypt:
`X = (X' - K) % 26`

Depending on what range of values you have for `pad`, the actual change to `decrypt` might be this:

```
num = (num + 26 - pad[pos++]) % 26;      //apply modular subtraction
```

Note the minus sign, and the additional +26 to ensure you have positive numbers after modulus.  This +26 only works if the values of `pad` are already limited 0 to 25.

Comment: ok so i got the encrypt to work, i'll add my main and the pad code...however I'm  supposed to use the pad as the keys are being used up.  I'll add the main code and pad to the original question.  I apologize for not doing so originally.